# Regular expression to prevent hotlinking from specific sites

Tags: nginx, hotlinking

I know how to implement something like the following in my Nginx configuration to prevent hotlinking. However, I don't mind hotlinking from most sources. Even though my website has nothing to do with porn, I have weird porn sites hotlink to my images. Would there be a way to modify the following config with a regular expression to filter any hotlinking from websites that contain things like porn or xxx in the address?  Thanks for the help.

```
location ~ .(gif|png|jpeg|jpg|svg)$ {
     valid_referers none blocked ~.google. ~.bing. ~.pinterest. ~.yahoo. mywebsite.com *.mywebsite.com;
     if ($invalid_referer) {
        return   403;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try negative lookahead, check this regex: `~^(?!.*(?:xxx|porn))`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry, I've tried to look at the valid_referers documentation but I'm still not sure how to implement this. I understand that the statement is saying to allow none, blocked, and those listed address headers. But how can I do the opposite which is to allow all except for headers that contain certain things listed in your regex?  Thanks for the help if this is possible.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew May I ask why you decided to remove the `regex` tag from this question? As for me, it is definitely a regex related one, and I'm not sure if my suggestion to use negative lookahead is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't check my regex, at least using some kind of online regex tester ([example](https://regex101.com/r/BZwgYI/1)), as well as you didn't care to find out what is [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#:%7E:text=Positive%20and%20Negative%20Lookahead) in regex world means. This is exactly what you were asking for, a regex that will match anything that doesn't contain a negative lookahead pattern. Try this and check how it will work:

```
location ~ .(gif|png|jpeg|jpg|svg)$ {
    valid_referers ~^(?!.*(xxx|porn));
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return   403;
    }
}
```

However this will block direct access to your images, and if this isn't desired, change that block to the following one (assuming your server names are not defined via a regular expression):

```
location ~ .(gif|png|jpeg|jpg|svg)$ {
    valid_referers none server_names ~^(?!.*(xxx|porn));
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return   403;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did look up a negative lookahead and I did an online regex test just like you suggested already. It's still a bit hard to understand if not familiar with regex. I guess I'm just not smart enough. I assumed I was misunderstanding something because when I tried it if I do an nginx test I get this error "nginx: [emerg] the "none" or "blocked" referers are specified in the "valid_referers" directive without any valid referer nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx-rc/nginx.conf test failed". I'll keep messing around and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault. Check the updated answer, please.